# Tweepy Check Blocked User?

Tags: python, tweepy

Is there a way to check if the user is blocked like an `is_blocked` method? The way I have it set up right now is to get a list of my blocked users and comparing the author of a Tweet to the list, but it's highly inefficient, as it constantly runs into the rate limit.

**Relevent Code:**

```
blocked_screen_names = [b.screen_name for b in tweepy.Cursor(api.blocks).items()]

for count, tweet in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = query, lang = 'en', result_type = 'recent', tweet_mode = 'extended').items(500)):
                    
        if tweet.user.screen_name in blocked_screen_names:
                continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll have to do that the way you're currently doing it.

(Also, just a side note, you're better off checking your blocked users via their account ID rather than their screen name, because this value will not change, whereas a user's screen name can)

For future reference, just check the Twitter API documentation, where you can get the answer for something like this straight away :) save yourself the waiting for someone to answer it for you here!

You'll notice that both the documentation for V1 and V2 do *not* contain an attribute as you have described:

**V1 User Object:**

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet

**V2 User Object:**

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/user

Comment: Is there not a faster way?

Comment: I don't believe so.